# Visualizing boolean time series in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

**Background:** I am using InfluxDB to persist states from my home automation setup (more specifically, I send MQTT changes via Node-RED) and would like to visualize window contact changes over time.  I have a "windows" measurement with a "contact" field that is a boolean true/false, tagged with the room / window name.  I have some experience with other visualization tools (Grafana, Kibana / OSD) but would think that using the built-in InfluxDB visualization would suffice (and keep the already high number of components in my home automation setup from exploding).

**Problem:** I found out that I need to change the aggregation from *mean* to *last* in order not to get an error, and I can find the correct time series.  However, I did not manage to find a suitable graph type.  The only non-trivial result I could achieve was with a scatter plot, in which I could at least see individual change events on the time axis.  I would have liked to visualize the two states (window open / closed) with different colors or at least different line graph height (that I could also fill below for a quick overview of the "window open" periods).  I tried filling missing values as well, but am afraid that it does not fill with the last measured value but with some kind of "NaN" or so.  (I should maybe stress again that I am not familiar yet with InfluxDB at all, so if one first needs to create a dashboard or set up other things, I would not know. I tried setting up the visualization in the "data explorer" for now, assuming that I could then save the result and use it as the basis for a dashboard.)

**Question:** (How) can I visualize a series of boolean values?  If the problem is that the visualizations are geared towards numeric values, I would be totally prepared and willing to convert the boolean to some numbers on the fly, but (how) can I do so in the data explorer?